# javafx project with multiple css .root{...}

Tags: java, css, javafx-2, fxml

I have a JavaFX project (in NetBeans) with multiple fxml files. Is there any way to assign individual css files for each of these fxml files? I want to make different .root{...} settings for each fxml. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to each `FXML` file the associated `css` file:

```
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@stylesheet.css" />
  </stylesheets>
```

Make sure that `stylesheet.css` is somewhere on the `CLASSPATH`.

**Edit**: if you want **one** global `css` for many `fxml` files, add the `fx:id` to the root pane in your `fxml` files , and use the `ID` in your `css`, `root` in the default value.

```
#fxml_1 {
  ... style from the fxml file with fx:id = "fxml_1", and so on
}
```

Comment: It's okay, but then the .root{...} record in the css file is ignored. So I want different .root{...} settings in every different css file. Is it possible?